# How to update record and its parent lookup record in single REST API

Tags: rest-api

We have a contact lookup field on Account object - which basically defines the primary contact of that account.

We have an integration to update account record and would need to update the primary contact in the same call. Is it possible to do ? External system does not have any reference to this primary contact and neither in salesforce (as external id).

I am trying to do as below

```
Account.Name = 'test'; //update account record
Account.Primary_Contact__r.FirstName = 'test first'; //update primary contact record
```

So basically it should be able to update both Account and its Primary Contact.

I found a way to do this using PATCH as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_relationship_traversal.htm). But it requires another call from Account update.

Comment: I've never tried this but [Composite Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_junction_object.htm) + [Traverse Relationships with Friendly URL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_relationship_traversal.htm) might work

Comment: @cropredy The Composite Request thing was my suggestion... why not add an answer? I don't need the rep. 

Answer (score 3):

TIL - You can update a specific parent object field while updating a child object by using a combination of

- [Composite Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_junction_object.htm)
- [Traversing Relationships with Friendly URL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_relationship_traversal.htm)

Composite resources are used to bundle multiple CRUD operations into a single REST call.

For your example, here is the POST body for endpoint `/services/data/v51.0/composite` I used in workbench:

```
{
"allOrNone" : true,
"compositeRequest" : [{
    "method" : "PATCH",
    "url" : "/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Account/0014000000HQGCNAA5",
    "referenceId" : "UpdatedAccount",
    "body" : {  
        "Name" : "test"
    }
},{
    "method" : "PATCH",
    "referenceId" : "UpdatedContact",
    "url" : "/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Account/0014000000HQGCNAA5/Primary_Contact__r",
    "body" : {  
        "FirstName" : "test first"
    }
}]
}
```

The response looks like this:

```
{
  "compositeResponse" : [ {
    "body" : null,
    "httpHeaders" : { },
    "httpStatusCode" : 204,
    "referenceId" : "UpdatedAccount"
  }, {
    "body" : null,
    "httpHeaders" : { },
    "httpStatusCode" : 204,
    "referenceId" : "UpdatedContact"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If there is no lookup value it will fail that particular resource, it is not creating a new one

Comment: True.  That isn't what you asked though